# meaning of ./configure --with-ssl=openssl

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, wget

I followed this [install wget tutorial](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/22/install-wget-mac-os-x/),

After I ran this

```
./configure --with-ssl=openssl
```

It ran so many checks, what exactly it did? Did it change anything in my system?

If it does, then, is it safer or more fault prove to use the package management tool like MacPort or such so that such 'configure' will not be done manually like this or does those tool do the same thing in order to make wget work?

Sorry, I am pretty noob on shell commands.

Thanks

Comment: technically, yes, it did change stuff in your system - it'll have written out makefiles, config files, blah blah blah so you can start building wget.

Comment: @Marc B Will it affect anything else in my system? I am kinda scared to proceed further. I have a git branch in my system. Will it affecting it? Does it only does stuff to that wget folder I am at when I ran this ./configure command?

Comment: if you do `make install`, you'll end up with a wget binary somewhere on your system. so yes, things will change. will it affect your git directory? no idea, probably not, but don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the build process. The `configure` script collects information about your system and build options into a local file, nothing more.

Typically, this script is created by `autoconf` and is used to figure out whether the prerequisites for a build are properly installed, etc. It will collect this into a file `config.save` and also possibly generate a `makefile` and/or other build infrastructure in order for `make` to be able to concentrate on compiling and linking the source files.

Neither `configure` nor `make` should be expected to change anything outside of the directory tree where you run them.

Conventionally, `make install` will copy the final build artefacts into place so that other parts of your system can find them and use them.

See also http://www.edwardrosten.com/code/autoconf/

A prepackaged binary will already have been built on a remote system before it was packaged (though there are package managers which allow or require you to build locally; Gentoo Linux famously uses the latter approach) and is often the simplest way to get a tool if you don't have special requirements, such as building with a specific SSL version, or disabling SSL entirely, or getting a bleeding edge version before anybody has packaged it.

Comment: Will it affect anything else in my system? I am kinda scared to proceed further. I have a git branch in my system. Will it affecting it? Does it only does stuff to that wget folder I am at when I ran this ./configure command?

Comment: I don't understand how this can be said any clearer. It only changes things in the `wget` directory. Even building with `make` will only modify things within this directory tree. Only if you `make install` will it affect the rest of your system.

Comment: ah that actually is the next step, to make and install. So if I did that, that will kinda change many settings in my system, but if I do not, nothing will be affected right? But if I stopped at this config step, will it prevent any future process or its just for that wget folder ONLY?

Comment: In another word, did the config has already been done system wise or its just getting ready to make that change once I do 'make' ?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed update. I updated my question, just to follow up, if possible you can update your answer accordingly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Updated some more. Yes, get a packaged version if all you care about is obtaining a run of the mill version of `wget`.